# Return type when returning values from multiple tables

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have two Models:

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public int Student_Id {get;set;}
    public string Student_Name {get;set;}
    public int Class_Id {get;set;}
}

public class ClassModel
{
    public int Class_Id {get;set;}
    public string Class_Name {get;set;}
}
```

I want to return values from both the tables. What should my return value be?

```
public ?? GetStudentClass(StageModel model)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LO"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string getstudent= $"select * from student s,class c where s.classid = c.classid and s.studentid = @studentid;";
        DynamicParameters parameter = new DynamicParameters();

        parameter.Add("@studentid", model.Student_Id, DbType.Int64);

        connection.Open();

        result = connection.Execute(getstudent, parameter);
    }
}
```

I should use the output of the SQL to print, using the model defined.

Comment: If you are returning multiple table results from a sql call, you can use `DataSet` found in `System.Data.`

Comment: Normally you'd have a `public ClassModel ClassModel { get; set; }` in `StudentModel`

Comment: If you really need that, define a new class that contains the properties from both.

Comment: @Amy I really don't think any of those answers is appropriate for this question

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Understood.  I so dislike being able to unilaterally close questions as dupes.  I wish I could turn that power off.

Comment: @Amy I could have reopened it, but wanted your opinion first. Thanks. By the way, I think that if you flag as duplicate it shouldn't close

Comment: Are you using Dapper? If you are using Dapper then why do you have class properties with different names from the database fields? It is just a typo or do you really have this difference? I recommend to name your properties exactly in the same way or you need a mapping layer to leverage the power of Dapper. (By the way `Execute` is not used to read data. You need the `Query<T>` method)

Comment: I would rename the method to `GetStudentClasses` and would expect it to take in an instance of a `StudentModel` (or just an `int studentId`) and return a `List<ClassModel>` representing the classes the student is taking. It looks like you have a `@studentid` parameter in your query, so the caller already has that? So they could call a different method to get the other student details if necessary. Otherwise, you could return a `StudentClasses` object, which would look like: `public class StudentClasses { public StudentModel Student { get; set; } public List<ClassModel> Classes { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using Dapper for your work. But you have differences between your properties names and your database fields names. This makes the work with Dapper more difficult, so I recommend to change your properties to match the names in the database fields.
With this changes you can get your classes filled automatically by Dapper

First your StudentModel needs to have an instance of the ClassModel declared in the class

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public int StudentId {get;set;}
    public string StudentName {get;set;}
    public int ClassId {get;set;}
    public ClassModel StudentClass {get;set;}
}

public class ClassModel
{
    public int ClassId {get;set;}
    public string ClassName {get;set;}
}
```

now you change the method in this way

```
public StudentModel GetStudent(StageModel model)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LO"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string getstudent=  @"SELECT s.*, c.ClassId, c.ClassName 
                             FROM student s
                             INNER JOIN class c on s.classid = c.classid 
                             WHERE s.studentid = @studentid;";
        DynamicParameters parameter = new DynamicParameters();
        parameter.Add("@studentid", model.Student_Id, DbType.Int64);
        connection.Open();

        result = connection.Query<StudentModel, ClassModel, StudentModel>
                 (getstudent, ((s, c) => { s.ClassModel = c; return s;}), 
                 splitOn:"ClassId", parameter);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Dapper will create for you the *StudentModel* instance and the *ClassModel* instance knowing how to fill the two instances when it meets the *ClassId* field.
The lambda expression will receive the two instances created by Dapper and you just need to set the ClassModel inside the StudentModel received by the lambda.

This approach follows the impression from your question that between a Student and a Class there is a 1:1 relationship. Of course the matter is more complex if the relationship is 1:N and you need a *List* inside the *StudentModel* class